# How can i bind list of string to StringFormat Xamarin

Tags: list, xamarin, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

can i bind multiple values to String format by binding it with list of strings?

```
                        Text="{Binding FaceFingerPrintRecognitionLabel, StringFormat='You will need to activate the {0} recognition function on your permitted phone and register at least one of your {0}s to control access to the permitted mobile'}"
```

In above can i bind List of string and use it in my text? I am unable to do it, is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML using `Converter` and `ConverterParameter`:

```
<ContentPage
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfConverter"
    ...
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:StringArrayConverter x:Key="stringArrayConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
    <Label Text="{Binding StringArrayArguments, 
                          Converter={StaticResource stringArrayConverter},
                          ConverterParameter='Arg1 {0} arg2 {1} arg3 {2}'}"/>
```

Example ViewModel:

```
public string[] StringArrayArguments { get; set; } = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
```

Example `Converter` implementation:

```
public class StringArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string[] strings && parameter is string format)
        {
            try
            {
                return string.Format(format, strings);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    //Must implement this if Binding with Mode=TwoWay
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: <Label
                        Text="{Binding BiometricAuthArgs, 
                          Converter={StaticResource stringArrayConverter},
                         ConverterParameter='Arg1 {0} arg2 {1}',
                          StringFormat='Any {0}s registered with {1} on this phone will be able to access JazzCash App'}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />

this does not work @Benl

Comment: The StringFormat is a format specifier for 1 (one) element.

Comment: Assuming BiometricAuthArgs is a string[] with two items, try 
<Label Text="{Binding BiometricAuthArgs, 
                      Converter={StaticResource stringArrayConverter}, 
                      ConverterParameter='Any {0}s registered with {1} on this phone will be able to access JazzCash App'}" 
                      VerticalOptions="Center" />

Answer (score 1):

In the way you describe it here, you are unable to do it. Unless, like what is produced in your example, you want to have the same value show up in multiple places. But I figure you want to have multiple values as well.

Probably your best option would be to use a value converter.

Implement one like this:

```
public YourObjectToDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var yourObject = value as YourObject;

        // Double check we don't have a casting error
        if (yourObject == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return $"You will need to activate the {yourObject.FirstString} recognition function on your permitted phone and register at least one of your {yourObject.SecondString}s to control access to the permitted mobile";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Generally not needed in this scenario
        return null;
    }

}
```

Of course, `YourObject` can be any complex object or an array of strings or whatever you want.

You will need to declare your converter in XAML. You can do it in the page directly or the `App.xaml` if you need it in several places. Do it like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingDemos"
         x:Class="DataBindingDemos.EnableButtonsPage"
         Title="Enable Buttons">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:YourObjectToDescriptionConverter x:Key="yourConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<!-- Your contents -->

</ContentPage>
```

And use it in a binding like this: `Text="{Binding FaceFingerPrintRecognitionObject, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}"`

Read more on value converters in Xamarin.Forms on the documentation page for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface